# How can I render a .ASPX page using my default _SiteLayout.cshtml file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a .aspx file. It contains within it all the code I need to render a part of my webpage. I need to call it within my _SiteLayout.cshtml file.

I have tried the usual way, by calling :

```
@{  
    Layout = "/Shared/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
}
        @RenderPage("Shared/page.aspx");
```

However this results in the error -

> [HttpException (0x80004005): The file "/Shared/page.aspx" could not
>   be rendered, because it does not exist or is not a valid page.]

The path is correct, /Shared/page.aspx is where the file is stored.

What can I do in this case?

Comment: why not just move the html code to the new _Layout.cshtml file and use the Razor engine?

Comment: might want to check out this blog post: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx

Comment: I am using the Razor engine in the .siteLayout file, however the .aspx file is very complex and would be difficult to migrate to Razor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the @html.RenderAction() method, and have another acion rendering the page.aspx? I haven't tried but would assume it would work.